# how to show specific tick value on highchart gauge?

Tags: highcharts, gauge

I want to show the value between the green and yellow and red plotBands.

in the example attached i want to show the values 135,172 (where the color are changing)

```
yAxis: {
min: 0,
max: 200,

minorTickInterval: 'auto',
minorTickWidth: 1,
minorTickLength: 10,
minorTickPosition: 'inside',
minorTickColor: '#666',

tickPixelInterval: 30,
tickWidth: 2,
tickPosition: 'inside',
tickLength: 10,
tickColor: '#666',
labels: {
    step: 2,
    rotation: 'auto'
},
title: {
    text: 'km/h'
},
plotBands: [{
    from: 0,
    to: 135,
    color: '#55BF3B' // green
}, {
    from: 135,
    to: 172,
    color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
}, {
    from: 172,
    to: 200,
    color: '#DF5353' // red
}]
},
```

[Working Example In JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/08grxtqs/)

[image]

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/08grxtqs/10/?

Comment: @ewolden can i see the tick values and add the fix ones? 0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200(the calculate by the chart) and add my (135,172)

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/08grxtqs/21/? This has ticks for every 20, and makes sure labels are not overlaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tickPositioner` function to define which ticks will be shown on the chart:

```
    tickPositioner: function() {
        var plotBands = this.options.plotBands,
            ticks = [],
            i = 0;

        for (i; i <= 200; i += 20) {
            ticks.push(i);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < plotBands.length - 1; i++) {
            ticks.push(plotBands[i].to)
        }
        return ticks;
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1kpt7dws/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner